# Barcode Detection preprocessing

Tags: python, image-processing, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am working on a project for barcode detection in python.
I have received an accuracy of 85% in my dataset and i want to improve it. i am using pyzbar for barcode detection.

- first my barcode is decoded in raw stage if not found it is preprocessed.
- In preprocessing i am using Resizing,Sharpening,Enhancing contrast and Denoising.
- if the barcode is still not decoded than object detection using [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/24/detecting-barcodes-images-python-opencv/) article is performed and the barcode image is cropped and fed as input to get detected.

what preprocessing techniques can i use to increase the accuracy?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Detecting a barcode in an image, or eventually reading the barcode? If you want to eventually read the barcode you should not clip the whitespace off the beginning and end of the barcode as the article does. I would avoid the pre-processing in general, as all are "lossy" and may result in corruption of the symbol.

Comment: I eventually want to decode the barcode and verify if it is true.
Thanks for your suggestion